# With Ruby Booleans, what are you checking for if there are no equality statements?

Tags: ruby

I am using a tutorial, and it has a conditional like this:

```
if Restaurant.method1
   puts "XXX"
elsif Restaurant.method2
   puts "YYY"
end
```

Both methods return a Boolean value of `true` or `false`. Similarly, for variables, I have seen something similar:

```
if x
  puts "XXX"
else 
  puts "YYY"
end
```

I am wondering what exactly are you checking for considering that there is no equality operator (`==`) or assignment operator (`=`)? There must be some sort of equality check that perhaps hidden by the simplistic nature of Ruby, because I'm thinking this logically in my head and "If x", and "If Restaurant.method" both don't really make any sense as a conditional without some sort of check.

Comment: It's exactly the same thing. In `if Restaurant.method1` is checks whether the return value of calling the method `method1` is truthy, in `if 2 == 3`, it checks whether the return value of calling the method `==` is truthy, in `if 'a' <= 'b'`, it checks whether the return value of calling the method `<=` is truthy. Why would it make any difference what the name of the method is?

Comment: I was wondering what exactly you were checking for. Without the ` == true` (which I believe that's what truthy means), there is no way to intuitively know what if x/method name does.

Comment: But `==` is just a method, *exactly* like `method1`. There is zero difference between the two, except for the name. So, why would there be a difference between two things which are exactly the same? Why should calling one method inside the condition of an `if` expression be any different from calling another method? In the case of `a == b`, the return value of calling the `==` method is checked for truthiness. In the case of `a.foo(b)`, the return value of calling the `foo` method is checked for truthiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common paradigm in programming, not a Ruby abstraction. You are checking if something is truthy. In ruby in particular, everything is truthy except `false` and `nil`. Try it yourself in your console if you want to test this:

```
!!1 # => true
!!0 # => true
!![] # => true
!!{} # => true
```

...etc, whereas

```
!!false # => false
!!nil # => false
```

Important note: this is only the case for Ruby. Other languages have different rules. For example, in some languages `0` is falsy. It's important to learn these early on when learning a new language.

Comment: Oh ok so in both cases, it's evaluating whether Restaurant.method and x is true? For Restaurant.method, seeing if it returns true via the return value, and for x, seeing if its been set to anything else but false and nil?

Comment: Whether it is truthy, not `true` (but `true` is also truthy). For example `true == 0 # => false`. `0` is not true, it is truthy, meaning it will evaluate to true if coerced via an if statement, ternary operator, etc. This is somewhat less of a hassle in Ruby, because it's pretty hard to shoot yourself in the foot with 2 falsy values. Take javascript where a litany of things are falsy and you will run into some trouble.

Comment: Lol haha... "truthy" right... lol that's pretty funny, but OK... truthy = not false or nil falsy = nil or false... got it thanks!

Comment: Yep that's the simplest way of putting it :) Just remember that is language specific.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has "truthy" statements. That means multiple things can evaluate to true. Everything in Ruby is true except nil and false.